# What information is stored in NTUSER.dat on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, user-profiles

What information is stored in the registry hive `NTUSER.dat`? Please try to be specific and avoid answers like "user settings."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User-specific registry entries.

[From MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa918365.aspx):

> "With the hive registry, each time a
>   new user logs on, a new directory is
>   created for that user with a separate
>   file for the user registry. This is
>   called the user profile hive. A user's
>   hive contains specific registry
>   information pertaining to that user's
>   applications, desktop, environment,
>   network connections, and printer
>   settings. The user profile hive
>   contains all data under the
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER key. When the
>   current user is logged off and another
>   user is logged on, the new user's hive
>   is mounted, and the data under
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER changes."

HTH